# sorting countries by name in javascript/vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm using [country-data](https://github.com/OpenBookPrices/country-data) library:

```
loadCountries() {
  return require("country-data")
  .countries.all.filter(country => country.name)
  .map(country => ({
    label: country.name,
    value: country.alpha3
  }));
},
```

i'm not be able to sort countries by name in my select component

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)

I think you want to use sort instead of filter.

```
var items = [
  { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
  { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
  { name: "And", value: 45 },
  { name: "The", value: -12 },
  { name: "Magnetic", value: 13 },
  { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});
```

In your case, this may work:

```
loadCountries() {
  return require("country-data")
  .countries.all.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name)
  .map(country => ({
    label: country.name,
    value: country.alpha3
  }));
}
```

You can also use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/localeCompare)

```
loadCountries() {
  return require("country-data")
  .countries.all.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  .map(country => ({
    label: country.name,
    value: country.alpha3
  }));
}
```

Comment: For your reference, (a, b) => a.name - b.name won't work as the compareFunction for sort()

Answer (score 1):

You can try using method [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead of filter:

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>
let countries = require("country-data").countries;

export default {
mounted() {
    let sortedCountries = countries.all
    .sort((c1, c2) => {
        if (c1.name < c2.name) return -1;
        if (c1.name > c2.name) return 1;
        return 0;
    })
    .map(country => {
        return {
            name: country.name,
            alpha3: country.alpha3
        };
    });

    console.log("sortedCountries: ", sortedCountries);
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

And you will see the output sorted by country names alphabetically as shown below:

[image]

**Updated**:

Probably better you should use [String.prototype.localeCompare(compareString[, locales[, options]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), and the locales and options arguments let applications specify the language whose sort order should be used and customize the behavior of the function.

```
<script>
let countries = require("country-data").countries;

export default {
mounted() {
    let sortedCountries = countries.all
    .sort((c1, c2) => c1.name.localeCompare(c2.name))
    .map(country => {
        return {
            name: country.name,
            alpha3: country.alpha3
        };
    });

    console.log("sortedCountries: ", sortedCountries);
  }
};
</script>
```

And you'll get a slightly different list:

[image]

Comment: @tomatito for your reference, (a, b) => a.name - b.name won't work as the compareFunction for sort() as in another answer.